# Firebase web push notifications working on localhost but not in dev environment

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, firebase-notifications

I have a simple web notification application based from [simply-notify](https://github.com/ireade/simply-notify).  [Here](https://notes-pushies.firebaseapp.com/) is the Subscribe page to subscribe for push notifications and [here](https://notes-pushies.firebaseapp.com/pages/dashboard/) is the Dashboard to send messages.

The push notifications work when the tab, browser, or the app is closed.  However I am trying to receive notifications when the tab, browser or app is in running, not focused and focused.  I have tried the `onMessage` and `setBackgroundMessageHandler` methods and its not working as I hoped for.  I have tried running it locally and I received push notifications without any issues.  Hope anyone can help out.

**firebase-messaging-sw.js**

```
importScripts('/__/firebase/3.8.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('/__/firebase/3.8.0/firebase-messaging.js');
importScripts('/__/firebase/init.js');

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

self.addEventListener('message', event => {
    if (event.data.type === 'received_message_inactive_tab') {
        const object = // turn payload into notifications object;
        self.registration.showNotification(object.title, object.options);
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe you need to include the dev environment as a white-listed domain or something? I haven't worked with Firebase in a while so only guessing. Might be something like that which you need to do.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz, already done it.  Otherwise, it wouldn't even proceed after login

Answer (score 0):

Firebase push notifications works in either *localhost or https*.
Your application is working well in localhost. So on your dev environment, whats the hosted/deployed url of your site?

Try to make it https:// and verify.

Comment: Its hosted in Firebase.  Its all working now.  I think I was just using the wrong event listener and expecting for the system notification to pop up even when the browser is open.